# Criterion for being reflexive via Ext

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, duality

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4590/when-are-dual-modules-free) it was claimed that if a module $M$ over a noetherian domain $R$ satisfies $\rm{Ext}^i(M,R)=0$ for $i=1,2$, then $M$ is reflexive. Is this true? Does someone know a reference or a proof for this? If it is not correct, is there another criterion for being reflexive via some $\rm Ext$-goups vanishing?

Comment: For $R=k[x,y,z,w]$, for the torsion-free, pure $R$-module $M=\langle x,y,z,w\rangle$, i.e., $M$ equals the maximal ideal of the origin, both $\text{Ext}^1_R(M,R)$ and $\text{Ext}^2_R(M,R)$ are zero.  This follows from the self-duality of the Koszul complex of the regular sequence $(x,y,z,w)$.  The module $M$ is not reflexive.

Comment: I am sure the poster of that answer just wrote the wrong pair of integers.  There is a characterization of reflexive modules in terms of the cohomological dimension for local cohomology.  If you translate that into Ext groups, there is probably a shift of degrees that got lost in the post.

Comment: If $R$ is a regular local ring of dimension $d$ so that we have local duality. Assuming that my computations are correct, a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ has depth $\geq 2$ (i.e., it is reflexive) if both $\text{Ext}^{d-1}_R(M,R)$ and $\text{Ext}^d_R(M,R)$ are zero.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit.** Hailong Dao points out a **serious error** in what I originally wrote.  I have edited the statement below.  Unfortunately, the corrected condition on the Ext modules is now rather complicated: a dimension condition on the support of every Ext module, not just vanishing of the final two Ext modules.

I am just writing my comments as an answer.  **Edit.**  *For a normal Noetherian integral domain $A$ and for a torsion-free, finitely generated $A$-module $N$, $N$ is reflexive if and only if, for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ of height $\geq 2$, for the local Noetherian ring $R=A_{\mathfrak{p}}, \mathfrak{m}= \mathfrak{p}A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and for the localized module $M=N\otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p}}$, the depth of $M$ is $\geq 2$ as an $R$-module.*
<del>For a local Noetherian ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ of dimension $\geq 2$ (**Edit:** that is normal), for a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ (**Edit:** that is torsion-free), $M$ is "reflexive" in the usual sense if and only if the depth of $M$ is $\geq 2$.</del>  Also, the depth is $\geq 2$ if and only if the local cohomology groups $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^i(M)$ are zero for $i=0,1$.  One reference is the exercises part of Section II.3, pp. 216-218, of Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry".  If $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a regular local ring of dimension $d$, then those local cohomology groups are dual (in the sense of local duality theory) to the Ext groups $\text{Ext}^{d-i}_R(M,R).$  This is Corollary V.6.8, p. 276, and the comments at the end of the section, p. 281, of Hartshorne's "Residues and Duality", cf. also 6.3 of "Local Cohomology".  <del>Thus, in the regular case, $M$ is reflexive if and only if both $\text{Ext}^{d-1}_R(M,R)$ and $\text{Ext}^d_R(M,R)$ are zero.</del>

**Edit. Corrected Necessary and Sufficient Ext Condition.** Assuming that $A$ is a regular Noetherian integral domain (so that also each localization $R$ is regular by Serre), this becomes a condition in terms of the Ext modules of the original module $N$ over the original ring $A$. A torsion-free, finitely generated module $N$ is reflexive if and only if, for every integer $e\geq 1$, every minimal associated prime of $\text{Ext}^e_A(N,A)$ has height $\geq e+2$, i.e., the support of the module has codimension $\geq e+2$.  For example, when $A$ is regular of dimension $2$, this is equivalent to saying that $N$ is projective.  When $A$ is regular of dimension $d \geq 2$, this condition implies that both $\text{Ext}^d_A(N,A)$ and $\text{Ext}^{d-1}_A(N,A)$ are zero, but  vanishing of these Ext modules is not sufficient.

Having explained that the wrong statement in that previous post seems to have just been a transcription problem (**Edit.** Hailong Dao points out that it is more complicated than I thought), it is straightforward to construct examples of modules $M$ that are not reflexive where $\text{Ext}^1_R(M,R)$ and $\text{Ext}^2_R(M,R)$ are zero.  Of course we need to choose $d>2$.  For $d\geq 4$, the maximal ideal $M=\langle x_1,\dots,x_d \rangle$ in $k[x_1,\dots,x_d]$ has vanishing $\text{Ext}^1_R(M,R)$ and $\text{Ext}^2_R(M,R)$, yet $M$ is not reflexive.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for this answer! Just two quick question: What happens for rings of dimension 1? Is it true that reflexive is equivalent to projective? And do you have a reference for your first statement, namely that the module is reflexive iff its depth is at least two?

Comment: The definition that I wrote is correct if $R$ is normal.  If $R$ is not normal, then you will find commonly used at least two inequivalent definitions, cf.  http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AY1.  If $R$ is normal, then every finitely generated, torsion-free $R$-module is reflexive at all points of codimension $0$ and codimension $1$.  Then one reference relating reflexive to depth $\geq 2$ is http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AY5.

Comment: It is not true that $M$ is reflexive if depth is at least $2$. Over a normal domain you need it to be $S_2$, a more subtle condition. For example, take $M=(x,y,z)$ in $k[x,y,z,t]$. It has depth 2 but not reflexive, since a reflexive ideal would have to have height one.

Comment: @HailongDao:  You are correct, and I will edit my answer.  For $M=\mathfrak{p}=\langle x,y,z \rangle \subset k[x,y,z,t]$, the module does have depth $2$ and one regular sequence of length $2$ is $(t,x)$.  Of course the localization $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ as a $k[x,y,z,t]_{\mathfrak{p}} = k(t)[x,y,z]_{\langle x,y,z \rangle}$ does not have depth $2$.

Answer (score 5):

About the last question, I should point out that there is indeed a Ext-vanishing criterion for reflexivity. Namely, $M$ is reflexive iff $Ext^{1,2}(Tr(M),R)=0$ where $Tr(M)$ is the Auslander-Bridger transpose of $M$. For details see for instance Lemma 2.2 in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.1958v3.pdf