# Normalization of complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, resolution-of-singularities

Let $A$ be an integral complete local ring over a field which is complete intersection.

Let $B$ be a normalization of $A$.

### Q. Is $B$ Gorenstein?

I guess that even the normalization of Gorenstein local ring should be Gorenstein.

Comment: No.  Every variety is the normalization of a hypersurface.  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68246/cohen-macaulay-domain-with-non-cohen-macaulay-normalization/68251#68251

Comment: @KarlSchwede: Well, every *normal* (projective) variety!

Comment: :-) that is true

Comment: [Cross-link to meta discussion](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2896/how-is-it-off-topic-to-ask-whether-the-normalization-of-a-local-complete-interse) about why this question was closed.

Answer (score 10):

Consider $A=k[[x^3,x^2y,y^3]]\subset k[[x^3, x^2y, xy^2, y^3]]=B$. $B$ is the integral closure of $A$, $A$ is a hypersurface, but $B$ is not Gorenstein.